# Session variable value not always available in Global.asax Session_end

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, global-asax

When a user logs into the website, I am creating 5 session variables with some user related values (like `userid`,`roleid` etc..). Based on one of the values stored in a session variable, I have to update a record in the database. To do this I am writing the following code in the `Session_End()` event of Global.asax

```
if (Session["UserHistoryID"] != null)
        SessionUtility.UpdateDatabase(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserHistoryID"]));
```

The problem here with this is when the Session times out and `Session_End` fires the `Session` variable `Session["UserHistoryID"]` is `NULL` some-time and the above condition fails and the record in the database is not updated. When this is tested in my local system it works fine but when I test this in production server some of the records are not getting updated

Why is this happening?

Some one please explain how the `Session_End` works exactly.

I have searched everywhere but can't find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I declare a variable for each session value I want to access in the Session_End event and store the value of the session in this variable and use the declared variable in the my functionality it is working fine

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int var=0;
   if (Session["value"] != null)
   {
      var = Convert.ToInt32(Session["value"]);
      UpdateToDatabase(var);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the earliest possible time you could obtain the `Session` value is under `Application_AcquireRequestState` as mentioned here[Sessions and Global.asax](http://forums.asp.net/t/889130.aspx/1) so you could write something like this in your `Global.asax`

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            if (Session["language"] != null)
            {
                Response.Write(Session["language"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

hopefully that would help !!

Comment: i want to access the session value when the session expires and do something there and not when it is created